# Is there any way to reduce multiple try catch conditions in ES6 js

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, puppeteer

Wanted to have simplified version of code using latest ES6 JS frameworks

```
async function ElementAttributeShouldBe(page, selector, attribute, attributeValue, fullMatch) {
    debugger
    let result = false
    let currentAttrValue
    try {
        currentAttrValue = await page.evaluate((_sel, _attr) => {
            let element = document.querySelector(_sel)
            return element.getAttribute(_attr)
        }, selector, attribute)
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to fetch the attribute (${attribute}) value (${attributeValue}) on selector (${selector})`)
    }
    if (fullMatch == true && currentAttrValue != null) {
        try {
            currentAttrValue.toLocaleLowerCase() == attributeValue.toLocaleLowerCase() ? result = true : result = false
            assert.isTrue(result)

        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Element attribute value is not expected for the selector ${selector}`)
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            currentAttrValue.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(attributeValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) ? result = true : result = false
            assert.isTrue(result)
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Element attribute value do not have expected value for the selector ${selector}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Was there any simplified way to reduce the number of try catch blocks. The above code is written using `puppeteer` and `mocha` for automation.

Comment: put all of your code in the first try? I see no reason for multiple here, just conditionally handle your different errors in one catch.

Comment: `currentAttrValue.toLocaleLowerCase() == attributeValue.toLocaleLowerCase() ? result = true : result = false` why use a conditional operator here? If it's to "make the code shorter", then it doesn't work as it is longer than `result = currentAttrValue.toLocaleLowerCase() == attributeValue.toLocaleLowerCase()`

Comment: A few other suggestions: too many arguments--use an object. Use `$eval` over `evaluate` + `document.querySelector`. `throw Error` rather than `throw new Error`. Always use `===` and `!==`. Generally don't use `if (something === true)`, just `if (something)`. Prefer `const` over `let`. `ElementAttributeShouldBe` should be `lowerCamelCase`.